# How to scale size of each 3d object independently

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have number of 3d objects I want to resize in an easy and fast manner.

My code is very similar to xoppa's card game example:

https://xoppa.github.io/blog/a-simple-card-game/

The objects are rendered using a `ModelBatch` and `RenderableProvider`:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    ...
    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(items);
    modelBatch.end();
    ...
}
```

Where items is a `ObjectSet` implementing `RenderableProvider`.

Each `item` vertices and indices are added using a `MeshBuilder`:

```
meshBuilder.begin(mesh.getVertexAttributes());
meshBuilder.part("items", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, renderable.meshPart);
for (Item item : this) {
    meshBuilder.setVertexTransform(item.transform);
    meshBuilder.addMesh(item.vertices, item.indices);
}
meshBuilder.end(mesh);
```

Now what I want to do is to resize the items to make some fancy animation effects. I guess I could use a `PerspectiveCamera` and change the distance parameter. But what if I want to resize each item independently?

To try solve this I multiplied the vertices (`item.vertices`) directly by the resize (scale) factor each in each `render()` call, but each `Item` has approx 140 vertices so I need to loop through them each time and multiply with the scaling factor.

I am thinking there might be a more effective way to resize each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `item.transform` matrix each frame to include a scaling operation; the entire point of using matrices is that are mathematically composable.

See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)

Comment: For some reason when I tried before it seemed like I scaled the position not the size. But now when I try again it actually works using Matrix4.scale() function. My bad :-)